# Create a table with all permutations of some column values in SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am working in SAS Enterprise guide and want to create a table that contains all possible permutations of some columns. Here is an example:

Lets say I have three columns

```
apple                   pear                      plum  

0                       good                      blue
1                       middle                    violet
                        bad
```

I would want my output table to look as follows:

```
apple        pear       plum

0            good       blue
0            good       violet
0            middle     blue
0            middle     violet
0            bad        blue
0            bad        violet
1            good       blue
1            good       violet
1            middle     blue
1            middle     violet
1            bad        blue 
1            bad        violet
```

My actual code has more columns with more distinct values, so hard coding is definitely not an option. How can I create such a table in SAS?

Thanks up front for the help!

Comment: What is it you don't want to hardcode? The values or the variable names? It is easy to avoid hardcoding the values.  Harder to avoid using the variable names.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode each observation. Variable names are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PROC SQL to create full cross product.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as
    select * 
    from (select distinct apple from have where not missing(apple))
       , (select distinct pear from have where not missing(pear))
       , (select distinct plum from have where not missing(plum))
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

PROC SUMMARY

```
data testx;
   input apple pear $ plum $;
   cards;
0 good   blue
1 middle violet
1 bad    blue
;;;;
   run;
proc summary nway completetypes chartype;
   class _all_;
   output out=testb(drop=_:);
   run;
proc print;
   run;

Obs    apple    pear       plum

  1      0      bad       blue  
  2      0      bad       violet
  3      0      good      blue  
  4      0      good      violet
  5      0      middle    blue  
  6      0      middle    violet
  7      1      bad       blue  
  8      1      bad       violet
  9      1      good      blue  
 10      1      good      violet
 11      1      middle    blue  
 12      1      middle    violet
```

Comment: Note that if your input data had missing values for APPLE and PLUM on the last observation then PROC SUMMARY will eliminate the PEAR='bad' records and only generate 8 instead of 12 records.  If you add MISSING option then PEAR='bad' is kept, but also the missing values of APPLE and PLUM are output.